# typescript - get compiletime type

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-class

I have I base class `GenericSetting` which is subclassed in approx 10 or more types.

```
export class GenericSetting {
  configuration: SettingArgs
  constructor(args: SettingArgs) {
    this.configuration = args
  }
}
```

as you can see it's also receiving arguments, which themsevles are subclassed to account for additional properties required by the subclasses.

I then create 100th of settings, as compact as possible

```
  FocusPos = new LensValuedSetting({ componentId:LensModule, key:"Focus-ActuatorPosition", displayName:"@{ActuatorPosition}", categories:["@{Lens}", "@{Focus}"], mode:EditMode.ReadOnly, stepSize:0, ctx:{ canId:7, dataType:"UInt16", bit:-1, startByte:2, rounding:1 }})
  FocusAuxActive = new LensValuedSetting({ componentId:LensModule, key:"Focus-AuxInputDeviceActive", displayName:"@{AuxInputDeviceActive}", categories:["@{Lens}", "@{Focus}"], mode:EditMode.ReadOnly, stepSize:0, ctx:{ canId:36, dataType:"Byte", bit:1, startByte:6, rounding:1 }}, )
  FocusAuxPos = new LensValuedSetting({ componentId:LensModule, key:"Focus-AuxInputDevicePosition", displayName:"@{AuxInputDevicePosition}", categories:["@{Lens}", "@{Focus}"], mode:EditMode.ReadOnly, stepSize:0, ctx:{ canId:36, dataType:"Int16", bit:-1, startByte:2, rounding:1 }}, )
```

The problem is that since TypeScript just infers the arguments passed, the `args` argument is actually of type `object` at runtime, also circumventing the constructors of all these sub-classed setting-arguments.

Now I thought I would just create the type being type-guarded in TypeScript within the base constructor and `Object.apply()` like this:

```
export class GenericSetting {
  configuration: SettingArgs
  constructor(args: SettingArgs) {
    const typedArgs = new <HOW DO I GET CTOR OF ARGS TYPE?>()
    Object.assign(typedArgs, args)
    this.configuration = typedArgs
  }
}
```

Obviously I have no info about the type-guarded/inferred type at runtime, so is there no way to do this in one spot? Must I write this logic in every sub-class?

Comment: TypeScript's type system only exists in compile time. The runtime code is always just JavaScript. Generally you do not (and should not) rely on those type information at runtime.

Comment: yes, hence my question how to get the type at design-time so I can explicitly convert it

Comment: Maybe I don’t understand what you want to do. What do you want to do in the constructor with the `new` and Object.assign?

Comment: a have various type of settings, and based on their type (configuration), I render them out differently. I also have a lot of default values for these settings and I dont want to have to specify them in those 100th of declarations. Since the implicitly created object `{...}` behave like the `...Args` type, but they actually never invoke the constructor of the respective type, they don't get the default values and I also don't know their type later on in code. So I want to apply the respective `...Args` constructor within the constructor of the `...Setting` itself, so I solve both problems

Answer (score 0):

After different tries with generics (very cumbersome in a more complex class hierarchy) I found a somewhat workable solution - which is to define an additional property on the `...Args` type: `_cfgType:any`, which I can now pass into the `...Args`object like this:

```
  FocusPos = new LensValuedSetting({ _cfgType:LensValuedSettingArgs, componentId:LensModule, key:"Focus-ActuatorPosition", displayName:"@{ActuatorPosition}", categories:["@{Lens}", "@{Focus}"], mode:EditMode.ReadOnly, stepSize:0, ctx:{ canId:7, dataType:"UInt16", bit:-1, startByte:2, rounding:1 }})
```

My GenericSettings base class constructor now looks like this and converts the inbound `args` to the correct type, applying all set default values of the respective sub-class:

```
export class GenericSetting extends ItemBase {
  configuration:SettingArgs

  constructor(args:SettingArgs) {
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(args._cfgType)) {
      const typedArgs = new args._cfgType()
      Object.assign(typedArgs, args)
      args = typedArgs
    }
    args['__type'] = args['__proto__'].constructor.name
    super(args)
    this.configuration = args
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant way, but at least it was minimal invasion for my code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like what you need is generics.

```
export class GenericSetting<T extends Configuration> extends ItemBase {
  configuration: T
  constructor(configClass: new (args: SettingArgs): T, args: SettingArgs) {
    const typedArgs = new configClass(args)
    ...
  }
}
```

On the other hand, what is the need of constructing the `typedArgs` within `GenericSetting`? The construction process doesn't seem to have dependency on the `GenericSetting` and thus it is in general to better keep the construction process outside.

i.e.

```
constructor(public configInstance: ...) { }
```

Comment: i tried it with generics too, problem is, I'd need to introduce generics in all levels of my sub-classes. the reason I'm passing the args in the CTOR is that this is the only way to easily fully initialize 100th of such objects with as few lines as possible.